# Azure - WebJobs - Use remote connection string

Tags: azure, connection-string, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I have **WebJobs** running under my **Azure Web App**. For **Web App** you can set that the **Web App** will use **remote connection strings** (that you setup on Azure portal).

Is it possible to do the same for **WebJobs**?

So they would be looking for remote connection string instead of using a connections string from (for example) "app.config".

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that a connection string setup on Azure Portal **overwrites** connection string with the same name in .config files. Which means that no additional setup is required.

**Azure Portal Connection string takes priority over local *.config connection string.**

I successfully tested this.

Answer (score 0):

Could you add the connection string as Web Config value that can be accessed by either the site or webjob?

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer

Comment: Agreed, but I'm apparently not allowed to comment until 50 rep!

Answer (score 0):

Further more details you could refer to this blog:[`Configuring Azure Web Jobs`](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/16/configuring-azure-web-jobs/).

The main steps are as follows:

1. Install `CloudConfigurationManager` package [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager)
2. Set your connection strings to the app setting.
3. Retrieve connection string using the `CloudConfigurationManager`:

   `var myConnectionString = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("MyConnectionString");`